# When my account is suspended and I'm addressed in a comment, please notify the user that I cannot respond

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-replies, account-suspension

Please inform (write in comments) the participants and readers continuing to communicate with me in my posts that I cannot respond because my account is suspended.

I have no ability to do it myself since my account was closed while I was in a middle of 2 dozens discussions (i.e. problems in the process of resolving).

For ex., already after ban I was addressed in:

- [Deploying a UDDI service](https://serverfault.com/questions/164669/deploying-a-uddi-service)
- [SQL Server Instance login issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/175581/sql-server-instance-login-issue)
- [xp client problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/174247/xp-client-problem/174765#174765)
- [Authenticated User Impersonation in Classic ASP under IIS7](https://serverfault.com/questions/175534/authenticated-user-impersonation-in-classic-asp-under-iis7/175543#175543)
- [SQL Server 2008 connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/175753/sql-server-2008-connection/175759#175759)

Comment: Do you mean 2 dozen mod 8?

Comment: *My prior comment was just wrong.  My apologies.*

Comment: @Bill: I don't know the reasons why he was suspended, and I assume they were good reasons, but why is it wrong for him to have posted this question here on meta?

Comment: @John: See the 1st revision of the post if you missed it.

Comment: @John Saunders: Because he's using meta to try and skirt around a suspension on SF.

Comment: Oooh... Actually, you guys know what?  I maybe misunderstood the original.  :(

Comment: @Bill - was gonna say...

Comment: I interpreted this to mean vgv8's asking for an automated "I'm not here right now" response to all comments directed at him.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I think you're right.  I misunderstood it to mean he wanted people to post stuff here for him to respond to.  My bad.  Meta suspension lifted.  (Shortest in history, unless I miss my guess.)

Comment: I don't think we need to do anything to make SO more usable for people who get themselves banned. Just concentrate on not getting banned and you won't have any more problems.

Comment: @Bill: I interpreted it to mean he wanted people reading this question to respond, on his behalf, to comments directed to him after his suspension started. He wanted us to comment saying, "he's not responding because he's banned".

Comment: @John B, how can I concentrate on something incomprehensible? I have no clue why was I banned and I had neither warnings nor notifications

Comment: @vgv8: If, after all this time and all the discussion centering on you, you still don't understand, I honestly don't know what else we can say.

Comment: @Bill, I just read the original revision of his post and I can't blame you for misunderstanding it :S

Comment: Do you know the definition of telling the invented on the fly lies for hours and even days  to a person who cannot respond to them in the nearest 6 months? having deleted his previous pertinent posts in MSO

Comment: Save this post, it will be deleted soon

Answer (score 24):

I just sent an internet wide broadcast to 255.255.255.255 with the following content:

```
vgv8 is out of office for 6 weeks, please hold that thought
```

So far everyone indicates they are willing to resume discussion in 6 weeks.

Comment: There is no point to joke with ppl having the opposite notions of humor and decency with yours

Comment: It is growing exponentially

Comment: I'm not willing to resume until 8 weeks.

Comment: @Philip: Ha, thanks. I never expected a shiny gold badge.

Answer (score 24):

**No**, this is not going to happen, getting suspended is a total edge case that the vast majority of users will never experience.

We will not spam our comment system or users inboxes with "away" messages while you are suspended.

Answer (score 7):

You know you could just act like an adult, read the faq, use your time to read the different sites here and familiarise yourself with the system. I agree it can be difficult for a beginner, but trust me its much less difficult if you stop fighting everything and everyone everytime.

To answer your question anyone clicking your profile can know you are suspended. And in your case everyone knows you are. :-)

Comment: I've been acting like him - I've read FAQs and meta-topics many times and, lately, when my posts were filled by hijacking comments/answers I was opening the corresponding meta-topics in MSF to send there the spammers. For ex., http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/761/is-it-site-for-professionals-or-against-closed (on which I was supended in a min) I opened in order to divert the same hijacking comments from my technical posts, For ex., in http://serverfault.com/questions/174196/workgroup-windows-users-or-groups-can-use-domain-accounts-but-not-vice-versa "@vgv8 - This place is not a university

Comment: and many others. We are apt to forget that children watch examples better than they listen to preaching

Comment: @pizdets Stop being so confrontationnal for starters. You ask if this site is against professionals? How do you think that sounds to a bunch of professionals? STop thinking like you are. Just post clear questions and follow the sites guideline. Now you are making enemies. on a forum. on the web.

Comment: -1 "its" should be "it's".

Answer (score 4):

There is merit in the *goal* of this, but not at all in the execution.

There are two user experiences to consider.

1. User *sending* an "@message" to a suspended user.
2. Suspended user *receiving* an "@message"

#### 1.  Sending a message to suspended user.

**All** communications on stack overflow are asynchronous.

Like email, you send the message and forget about it. For this reason, sending a message to a suspended user is identical to sending a message to a user who is offline: you may get a response eventually. We wouldn't want the user to send their messages *differently* to a suspended user, because it would almost certainly make them *less* charitable.

#### 2. Suspended user receiving a message.

This is a little more frustrating an experience. The suspended user cannot respond, and cannot mark the message as something to remember. The only way for them to keep track of the things they want to say is to manually keep track of it.

However, suspension are not meant to relaxing enjoyable experiences. The 'ease-of-use' while suspended is *supposed* to approach zero.

**Suspensions should only inconvenience the suspendee.** This means that the other users should be *completely* unaware. Any pop-up or notification serves to annoy the other users, and shame suspended user. Both of those are negative side-effects of this feature.

Comment: Ah, I see the conveniences of speaking person  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/765/can-we-just-get-rid-of-vgv8 previously banning him, is not it? It is not the first one, it is long established convenience here. I recall, I was even invited to chat room being simultaneously banned from access to it

Answer (score 1):

If someone is really anxious to get a reply from you, I would imagine that they would click on your name to go to your profile which will tell them when you were 'last seen'.

Upon doing so, someone will be alerted to the fact that you are suspended.

I've had conversations in comments that protracted for *months* with weeks passing between replies. That is not at all uncommon.

I think you might be experiencing a greater than needed sense of urgency when it comes to replying to people. Even if you *weren't* suspended, most SO/SF/SU users realize that people answer when time and interest permit.

There are some interesting proposals at Area51, why not go see if any of them interest you while waiting for your suspension to end?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the feature on some forums and I think that it's good for the users, trying to write to a suspended user.
When you want to answer to a suspended user, you see that his name is stroked-through. This may prevent you from wasting your time writing to the user. I see this as an advantage for the non-suspended users.