# Mark (highlight) suspended users

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension

Mostly inspired by [When my account is suspended and I'm addressed in a comment, please notify the user that I cannot respond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62743/when-my-account-is-suspended-and-im-addressed-in-a-comment-please-notify-the-us)

IMO using automatic comments, as proposed, is not a solution, but I would *hate* to write a comment to someone who is suspended. I normally do not check the profile before writing.

I suggest *highlighting* (*lowlighting*?) the user name of an suspended account, when it is displayed as author of questions, answers and comments; e.g. using strikethrough or an yellow foreground/background.

I think there are't be that many suspended accounts, I'm not sure if it is worth the effort of doing so, but I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 9):

No, we don't believe in putting obvious [scarlet letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Letter) like this on every single thing people have posted.

Their reputation is locked to 1 for the duration of the timed suspension; that should be sufficient clue that you're dealing with someone who may or may not respond to you, like any other new unknown user.

And of course if you're interested enough to click through to their profile, the timed suspension information is already shown at the top, there..

Comment: I see your point... and reputation is a good hint (at least for comments)

Comment: Isn't the reputation of 1 like a scarlet letter, especially when the user is well known to have a rep in the 1000s?